# How to autoshare scheduled YouTube uploads on Facebook

Tags: facebook, youtube, if-this-then-that, automation, scheduling

On my YouTube account, I use scheduling of uploads a lot. The problem is when I do this IFTTT won't "see" my uploads. The only thing that it looks for is when you upload something publicly, and not when you upload something and then schedule it.

A similar question is this one: [How to autoshare uploaded YouTube videos to Facebook fan page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46370/how-to-autoshare-uploaded-youtube-videos-to-facebook-fan-page/46376#46376) but the IFTTT recipe solution there does not work for *scheduled* uploads.

I love IFTTT, but if I would have to use another service to catch my scheduled uploads for posting it to FB, then so be it. My IFTTT recipies would then catch the FB post and share it on my other social accounts.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to autoshare uploaded YouTube videos to Facebook fan page?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46370/how-to-autoshare-uploaded-youtube-videos-to-facebook-fan-page)

Comment: @Alex are you serious about that comment? My own text _"A similar question is this one: How to autoshare uploaded YouTube videos to Facebook fan page? but I have already tried the solution, and it didn't work."_ wasn't enough to point out that I HAVE visited that page, and that this is in fact an another situation?

Comment: Well, honestly, unless you explain why/how your circumstances are different than in that other question we still end up with a duplicate. If the solution offered in the other question no longer works (assuming it worked in the first place) then that answer needs to be downvoted and possibly removed.

Comment: Also, the text from Alex's comment is automatically added on a vote-to-close-as-duplicate. It's not intentionally snarky.

Comment: Okay, now that I'm off my phone and on a desktop screen, I've read your question more closely. This isn't a duplicate. You're specifically asking about _scheduled_ uploads rather than direct uploads, which the IFTTT solution in the other question apparently doesn't handle.

Comment: Exactly @AlE., thanks for editing the question so that it's clearer for everyone. English is not my first language, which gives my some problems with the grammar.
Should the "This question may already have an answer..." part be removed? I'm just thinking that it might keep some from leaving an answer?

Comment: I have been looking at Zapier, but I do not know if Zapier can solve the problem. At least I can not make it work :/

Comment: @AlE. I got Zapier to work, and have now submitted an answer. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Cool, thanks @AlE. I will be able to accept it in two hours or something like that.

Comment: @AlE. Should I add to the answer for the "duplicate question", or should they be kept separate?

Comment: Only if it is customized to answer that question. Don't copy-paste.

Comment: @AlE. If I suggest an edit of an answer, it will have to be approved before it will be shown publicly, right?
Or should I post my own answer?

Comment: Post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

[IFTTT](http://www.IFTTT.com) can't handle sheduled published videoes. Their support clarified this for me when I contacted them.

The free service [Zapier](http://www.Zapier.com), on the other hand, can solve this problem for you. I modified this zap a little: <del>http://zpr.io/GTQz</del> (the link is now broken) and it works like a charm.

Now I have Zapier zap a link from YouTube to my Facebook every time a shedueled video goes live.

I do not know how the mechanics of each service is set up, but I think the reason why Zapier handles the scheduled videos well, is that it checks a specific user every 5th minute, and doesn't rely on some kind of trigger from YouTube.

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: @johndpope I no longer have access to the zap I created (changed job), so I cannot provide a new link. My apologies, hope you find a solution

Comment: IFTTT can't handle sheduled published videoes. neither zapier.

Comment: @delive it could it 2014, we used it actively at my workplace at that time. If they removed that feature I don't know